# Customize DatePicker color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles, android-datepicker

I've a `DatePicker` inside xml, so it's not a dialog, just a component inside my layout. My main theme is extending from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`.
How can I change the color of my DatePicker, in particular header background and color accent for day and year selected? I don't want an alert dialog, the widget inside the xml it's perfect for my design. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: please possibly without changing "colorSecondary" globally to the whole theme.

Answer (score 3):

Using theme attributes and styles in res/values/styles.xml (themes all date pickers and affects other components):

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/shrine_pink_100</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/shrine_pink_900</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceMediumComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.MediumComponent">
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

or using a default style theme attribute, styles and a theme overlay (themes all date pickers but does not affect other components):

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.DatePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.DatePicker" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/shrine_pink_100</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/shrine_pink_900</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceMediumComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent</item>
    <!-- Customize text field of the text input mode. -->
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.App.TextInputLayout</item>
  </style>
```

or setting the theme in code (affects only this date picker):

```
val picker =
   MaterialDatePicker.Builder()
      ...
       .setTheme(.style.ThemeOverlay_App_DatePicker)
```